# make fails to build squid with openssl (deprecated functions used)

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, openssl, squid

I'm trying to build squid with openssl, but fail because make `threats warnings as errors`

An example: `gadgets.h -> error 'void RSA_free(RSA*)' is deprecated; Since **Openssl 3.0.0** -Werror=deprecated-declarations ..`

I assume that `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` instructs make to threat these warnings as errors. But in which file is `-Werror=deprecated-declarations`? How can I suppress this / avoid it?

I need squid with openssl.

Comment: does make -k fix it? prob not because it just skips it

Comment: It's not _make_ that's doing this.  It's your compiler.  make doesn't compile your code, so it doesn't show errors like this.  Make invokes your compiler and your compiler compiles your code, and shows errors like this.  There's no way we can know what's happening because you haven't shown us the compile line that generated these messages, and we can't help you fix it because you haven't shown us what part of your makefile invokes your compiler and what make variables it uses and what those variables are set to.  In short, none of this is "built into" make it all depends on your makefile.

Comment: I thought there's a trick to ignore it.. Because deprecated doesn't mean failed

Comment: There is a GCC option to not show deprecation warnings; for example `-Wno-deprecated-declarations`.  However we can't help you add it since we have no idea what your makefile looks like.

Comment: I can send the makefile.. Please note that the answer's solved now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can compile the latest version by openssl 3. It should be fixed

check https://github.com/squid-cache/squid/commit/3db8afad158dcdaa9390d8b998239e5763ae2cf4

# squid -v

Squid Cache: Version 5.7-VCS 
Service Name: squid

This binary uses OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022.

Ha Ha！

Answer (score 5):

**france1** answers correct. But maybe "step by step" commands will help to someone. I successfully built Squid 5.5 on Ubuntu 22.04 with Openssl 3.0.2.

Download openssl 1.1.1j:

```
cd /tmp/
wget https://github.com/openssl/openssl/archive/refs/tags/OpenSSL_1_1_1j.zip
```

Extract and install openssl to **/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j** from source

```
unzip openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1j.zip 
cd ./openssl-OpenSSL_1_1_1j/
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j/ssl
make
sudo make install
```

Export vars

```
export PATH="/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j/bin:$PATH" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j/lib/pkgconfig
```

Download squid and compile with custom openssl:

```
wget http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v5/squid-5.5.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ./squid-5.5.tar.gz 
cd squid-5.5/
./configure --enable-ssl-crtd --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl_1_1_1j/lib
make
sudo make install
```

Works!

Answer (score 2):

These things are deprecated **since Openssl 3.0.0**.
I just used **Openssl 1.1.1 LTS** - and it worked!

But later on I noticed that there's a squid-openssl in the ubuntu 20.10 repository.. so I installed that.

Openssl 1.1.1l: https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1l.tar.gz

Comment: hmm I have to wait a day to accept my answer